# Parallax Occlusion Mapping with Silhouettes

Tags: 3d, shader, gpu

Does anyone knows how to implement the correct silhouettes effect in [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcAsJdo7dME)?

Actually, I understand (and successfully implemented) the parallax occlusion mapping algorithm, but I have no ideas on how the silhouettes effect is being archived.

I had found [this paper](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/Dachsbacher-Tatarchuk-Prism_Parallax_Occlusion_Mapping_with_Accurate_Silhouette_Generation%28SI3D07%29.pdf) on the internet, but it provides very limited details on the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The video actually doesn't show correct silhouettes. You can see that it's not correct when he looks at a wall at a 90 degree angle: When you look inside the gaps from the side they're just black, you can't look through them.

[image]

It's just a cube, so you have quads at right angles. It looks like they simply clamp the u,v coordinates to 0,1 and discard if they're outside.